# User-defined function that uses an in-built Calc function

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Consider the following user-defined function:

```
Function LIMPA(x as String) as String
    Dim oFunctionAccess As Object
    oFunctionAccess = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    LIMPA = oFunctionAccess.callFunction("REGEX", Array(x, "^\d+\:\d+\sPM", "", 0))
End Function
```

Unfortunately, this function does not return the correct result for the following string:

```
5:32 PMMuitas letras
```

The result should be

```
Muitas letras
```

but I am getting exactly the same string, that is:

```
5:32 PMMuitas letras
```

Moreover, I get an error if I try to run the function as an array formula.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: OK, what about *.callFunction("REGEX", Array(x, "^\d+\:\d+\sPM", "", **1**)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument of 0 indicates not to match any occurrences. This works:

```
MsgBox oFunctionAccess.callFunction(_
    "REGEX", Array("5:32 PMMuitas letras", "^\d+\:\d+\sPM", "", ""))
```

To match exactly one occurence, specify `1` as mentioned by @JohnSUN.

If you enter `=REGEX` and look at the tooltip text, it says:

> Occurrence: Text specifying option flags, "g" for global replacement. Or number of occurrence [sic] to match or replace.

You also mentioned trying an array formula. In that case, `x` is a two-dimensional array. Here is a version that handles both normal calls and array formula calls.

```
Function DoReplace(x as String) as String
    Dim oFunctionAccess As Object
    oFunctionAccess = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    DoReplace = oFunctionAccess.callFunction(_
        "REGEX", Array(x, "^\d+\:\d+\sPM", "", ""))
End Function

Function LIMPA(x)
    If IsArray(x) Then
        Dim results(1 to UBound(x), 1 to 1) As String
        For y = 1 to UBound(x)
            results(y, 1) = DoReplace(x(y, 1))
        Next
        LIMPA = results()
    Else
        LIMPA = DoReplace(x)
    End If
End Function
```

I suppose I ought to have handled the case where the array formula spans multiple columns, but you could add that if needed, for example `Dim results(1 to UBound(x, 1), 1 to UBound(x, 2)) As String`.